What is the "Royal Air" in Dickinson's poem 788 (Publication – is the Auction)?
The third stanza of Dickinson's poem 788 (Publication – is the Auction) goes like this:

Thought belong to Him who gave it –
Then – to Him Who bear
It's Corporeal illustration – sell
The Royal Air –

The "Him who gave it" presumably refers to the "White Creator" (i.e. God). The "Corporeal illustration" is the poetry or work that is being published, so "Him Who bear / It's Corporeal illustration" would refer to the author. But what is the "Royal Air" that is being sold to the author? It's not a term I'm familiar with, and its meaning isn't - at least to me - immediately apparent from the text of the poem. The phrase sounds like "royal heir", a perhaps more common term, but the choice of "Air" seems to be very intentional.
What is the "Royal Air" and why is it being sold to the author?

Is the "Royal Air" being sold to the author, or is the author selling it?

I think that depends on how you parse the lines, @PeterShor; I parsed it as "to [the author] sell", but it could also be parsed "Thought belong to [God] then to [the author], sell...." Dickinson's punctuation (or notable lack thereof) leaves both possibilities open, I think.

I understand your parsing now. My first impression was that "The Royal Air" was the air (which is Royal because it is owned/provided by God), and that the author is trying to sell it, which Dickinson considers somewhat unethical. But I certainly don't understand the poem well enough to write an answer.

Dickinson’s use of dashes rather than conventional punctuation creates ambiguities of parsing. The question parses the third verse as:

Thought belong to him who gave it. Then, to him who bear its corporeal illustration, sell the royal air.

In this interpretation, “him who gave it” is the writer, “him who bear” is the reader, taking “bear” in the sense of “carry”, and “corporeal illustration” is the physical embodiment of the thought, that is, the published book.
But there’s another way to parse this, which is to suppose an enjambment between the third and fourth verses:

Thought belong [first] to him who gave it, then to him who bear its corporeal illustration. Sell the royal air in the parcel [if you must], be the merchant of the heavenly grace, but reduce no human spirit to disgrace of price.

For what it’s worth, the first published edition of the poem regularized the punctuation similarly to this. See Martha Dickinson Bianchi and Alfred Leete Hampson, editors (1896), Poems by Emily Dickinson, page 277, Boston: Little, Brown.
In this interpretation, “him who gave it” is god, and “him who bear” is the writer, taking “bear” in the sense “produce flowers or fruit”, and “corporeal illustration” is the manuscript.
I prefer this way of parsing it, because of the clearer sense of “then” meaning “next”, the parallelism in the second sentence, and the more vivid sense of “bear”.
In either case, the meaning of “royal air” is difficult. The wording is parallel to “heavenly grace” and “human spirit”, so I think it’s most compelling if we take all three of these terms to be precious qualities of a writer’s output, for example, we could take “air” in the sense “demeanour, manner, expression”. “Air” also means “breath” and so metaphorically “spirit”, but the poet says that we may sell air, but must not sell human spirit, so I don’t think we can take it in that sense here. However, it is not clear how we are supposed to separate these aspects of creativity: air, grace, and spirit are all embodied in the writing so how can it be permissible to sell the first two (in case of need) and not the third? This is a paradox to which I do not see a resolution, and maybe that’s the poet’s point.

Maybe Emily Dickinson's point is that you should write what you want, and then (if you need to) sell it, but don't mutilate your writing just for the sake of publication. I believe that some of her idiosyncratic poems were changed to a more conventional form for the sake of publication, and I vaguely remember reading that she disliked this.

And let me add that I think it's very lucky for us that she resisted changing her poems to more conventional forms for the sake of publication.

@PeterShor The 1890 Todd and Higginson edition used conventional punctuation, as did the 1896 Bianchi and Hampson edition, and many editions that followed these. I am not sure which was the first edition to restore the poet's own punctuation—perhaps the 1951 Johnson edition?

Also, a handful of her poems were published during her lifetime, and I believe they also used conventional publication. Do we know what she thought of this?

@PeterShor Higginson wrote in 1891, "I tried a little,—a very little—to lead her in the direction of rules and traditions" but her letters to him show a polite but implacable determination to persist in her own style.
